# Running flipper with expo sdk43

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo, flipper

I'm following the instruction in this tweet from an expo dev so that I can use flipper for debugging a bare workflow expo RN app. https://twitter.com/Baconbrix/status/1412923662546608130

1. I installed flipper on windows per the docs.
2. Running an emulator with android studio.
3. The emulator appears in the flipper desktop app.
4. Added the following to my `app.json`

```json
 "extra": {
    "flipperHack": "React Native packager is running"
  }
```

5. Ran `expo start METRO_SERVER_PORT=19000 -a Flipper.app`

I get the following error:

```
The expected package.json path: D:\dev\repos\foretold\foretold-react-native\Flipper.app\package.json does not exist
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a command for mac and not windows.
From the answer of the tweet you need to use this command : `npx cross-env METRO_SERVER_PORT=19000 path/to/Flipper.exe`

But for now you can only use react dev tools and console log like any other debugger.  You can't use any plugins

Edit : also you don't need to use the hack in app.json anymore

Comment: Can I use flipper in eas build?

Comment: @AyushKumar You can't really use it anywhere else other than eas build.